# Setting Column Widths using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm Trying to Figure out how to set column widths and heights using javascript so that i can set them according to the browser window. i figured the following code. but its not working. please help

```
<script type="javascript">
function size()
{
                    document.getElementById("body").style.width=window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("body").style.height=window.innerHeight;
var width=document.getElementById("body").style.width;
var height=document.getElementById("body").style.height;

document.getElementById("header").style.height=(.15*height);
document.getElementById("loginbox").style.height=(.15*height);
document.getElementById("navigation").style.height=(.05*height);
document.getElementById("leftpanel").style.height=(.70*height);
document.getElementById("contentarea").style.height=(.75*height);
document.getElementById("addcolumn").style.height=(.75*height);
document.getElementById("footer").style.height=(.10*height);

document.getElementById("header").style.width=(.75*width);
document.getElementById("loginbox").style.width=(.25*width);
document.getElementById("navigation").style.width=(width);
document.getElementById("leftpanel").style.width=(.20*width);
document.getElementById("contentare").style.width=(.65*width);
document.getElementById("addcolumn").style.width=(.15*width);
document.getElementById("footer").style.width=(width);
}    
</script>
```

i use css to float the columns according to requirement.
and then i'm calling the function size() in body ( onload=size() )

but not working

Comment: and you 100% sure that function running ?

Comment: So you have an element which ID is `body`? Seems strange, maybe you wanted to refer to `document.body`?

Comment: i removed the ' type=javascript ' and added a document.write("hello"). it was printed

Answer (score 2):

style attributes are strings and need a unit in the end:

```
document.getElementById("addcolumn").style.width=(width + "px");
```

Chances are you've also need to set width and height as:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you were to post a link to the page, or a fiddle, it would be a lot easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different way to accomplish this, which will be easily mantainable:

```
function size() {
    var props = {
        header: {
            width: .75,
            height: .15
        },
        loginbox: {
            width: .25,
            height: .15
        },
        navigation: {
            width: 1,
            height: .05
        },
        leftpanel: {
            width: .2,
            height: .7
        },
        contentarea: {
            width: .65,
            height: .75
        },
        addcolumn: {
            width: .15,
            height: .75
        },
        footer: {
            width: 1,
            height: .1
        }
    },
        bodyElement = document.getElementById('body'),
        width = bodyElement.style.width = window.innerWidth,
        height = bodyElement.style.height = window.innerHeight;

    for (var id in props) {
        if (!props.hasOwnProperty(id)) continue;
        var element = document.getElementById(id),
            prop = props[id];
        element.width = (width * prop.width) + "px";
        element.height = (height * prop.height) + "px";
    }
}
```

**Note**: I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: can u explain mein the condition in the for loop. i dont knw what it means

Comment: have you defined a array and are using a foreach loop?

Comment: i tried using it. but it didnt work. is there any way i can send u the code m typing?

Comment: Not without showing it to everyone. There is jsfiddle.net if you need to make a fiddle(or jsbin). Are you calling the function `size()` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple css, make the width a percentage,

```
width: 75%;
```

Comment: width 75% of what? i have to take some value so that its percentage is defined. and that is why i'm trying to take the value as the brower width

Comment: if the div is a child of something, its width will be according to its parent, so if the parents width is the size of the browser, then it would work, you didn't post your html

Comment: yes. thats my ques. how to set the parent width equal to the size of the browser!